# non vanishing $H^1$ on curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

let $C: x^e+y^e+z^e=0$ the Fermat curve of degree $e$ over a field $k$. Consider $\mathcal{O}(1)$ the restriction to $C$ of the polarization of $\mathbb{P}^3$. Let $L$ be a line bundle on $C$ of degree $m>0$. Let us also fix a positive integer $n$. 
I would like to know for which triples $(L,m,n)$ of line bundles/degree/positive integer is it true that 
$$
H^1\Big(C,\mathcal{H}om\big(L,\mathcal{O}(n)\big)\Big)\neq 0
$$

regardless the characteristic of the ground field.

Thanks

Comment: You can start by identifying $\mathcal Hom(L, O(n))$ with $O(n)\otimes L^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

@QiL8 I would like to use Serre duality $H^1\cong H^0(C,L\otimes \mathcal{O}(-n)\otimes \omega_C)$ and $\omega_C\cong\mathcal{O}(e(e-3)p)$ where $p$ is a Weierstrass point. A condition for the vanishing could be $\deg(\mathcal{O}(e(e-3)p)\otimes L\otimes \mathcal{O}(-n))<0$ so that $\deg(L)< \deg(\mathcal{O}(-n)) - e(e-3)$ is enough. How do you compute $\deg(\mathcal{O}(n))$? It should be not $n$ because I have restricted the bundle on $\mathbb{P}^3$ to the curve. Is that correct? Do I only need this simply condition on the degree?

Comment: The general idea is correct. Some comments: (1). Why does it exist a $p$ in the isomorphism with $\omega_C$ ? Anyway you don't really need $p$, just the degree of $\omega_C$. (2) The OP wants $H^1\ne 0$, not the vanishing. (3) $\deg(O(n))=n\deg O(1)=ne$ because $\deg O(1)$ is the intersection number of $C$ with a line, hence equal to $\deg C$ by Bézout.